# Redirection loop when url rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to avoid having 2 different urls for my landing page so I want to redirect landing page that has no culture specified (`www.example.com`) to `www.example.com/en-us`

What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect links that ends with **example.com** to **example.com/en-us**

This is my rule in web.config:

```
    <rule name="Redirect to En Us" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/en-us" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

But it just stuck in a redirection loop even if the url is not ending with **example.com**

**Update:**

This doesn't fall in a loop but it doesn't redirect either (seems that regular expression doesn't match at all but why?):

```
<rule name="Redirect to En Us" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="example.com$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/en-us" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally got it figured. I just had to tell that if the url (excluding the host name) is empty then redirect:

```
<rule name="Redirect to En Us" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />       
  <action type="Redirect" url="/en-us" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

You might need to look for a trailing slash too but in my case as I already have a rule that removes trailing slashes its not an issue.